# Square API Authentication Error when called from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, square

I have a stored proc that needs to make a call to the Square API AddCustomer. It's using native TSQL and oa procs. I know the risks associated with oa procs, but this is what I have, so whilst I realise the best approach would by a CLR, I have what I have.

When I translate this to a SQL call, it gives me an authentication error:

> {"errors":[{"category":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","code":"UNAUTHORIZED","detail":"Your
>   request did not include an `Authorization` http header with an access
>   token. The header value is expected to be of the format \"Bearer
>   TOKEN\" (without quotation marks), where TOKEN is to be replaced with
>   your access token

I've tested the call in Postman and it executes fine there.

```
  DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64)
         ,@contentType NVARCHAR(64)
         ,@responseText NVARCHAR(2000)
         ,@responseXML NVARCHAR(2000)
         ,@ret INT
         ,@status NVARCHAR(32)
         ,@statusText NVARCHAR(32)
         ,@token INT
         ,@url NVARCHAR(256)

  SELECT @authHeader = 'Bearer sandbox-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xx'
        ,@contentType = 'application/json';

  SELECT @url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers'

  -- Open the connection.
  EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
  EXEC  sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'post',@url, 'false'

  EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', null, @body

  EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
  Select @ResponseText
```

As you can see, I have the authentication set (the sandbox token is correct but removed here).

I can't figure out why it's not setting the headers correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader;
```

It should be:

```
EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader;
```

The correct header for [Bearer authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) is **Authorization**